# How to add html elements to a future html element (react or js preferred)

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

I'm trying to add some accessibility elements to some html that gets loaded in through a third-party, once the third party application is clicked the element spawns some li's with anchors that I need to append accessibility onto.
I was trying something like this in my index.html as a script tag but they obviously aren't there on the load, and working with a SPA I've gotten a bit lost.

```
var links = document.querySelectorAll("[class^='table__checkview']");
for (let i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
  links[i].setAttribute("role","button");
  links[i].setAttribute("tabindex","0");
}
```

Comment: How does the html of the third-party get loaded? via a script tag?

Comment: How and, likely more important, when is the 3rd-party code loaded and available in the DOM to be appended to?

Comment: You can use the `.onload` function which triggers when the element is loaded

Comment: It's loaded via a script tag but doesn't appear until after a login screen, using `pendo.io`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use conditional components and a useState hook. When your third-party is clicked, the state gets true and if the state is true, then your UI is going to show the elements that you want.
https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html